# TriMerge vs Merge Sort

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

Can some one tell me which is better of the two algorithms `TriMergeSort` and `MergeSort`. 
The time complexity of the `MergeSort` would be nlogn base 2.
The time complexity of the `TriMergeSort` is nlogn base 3.

Since `TriMergeSort` is base 3 and `MergeSort` is base 2 I am considering `TriMergeSort` is faster than that of `MergeSort`.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

While you are right that the number of levels in the recursive structure is log<sub>2</sub> n in the case of regular mergesort and log<sub>3</sub> n in the case of three-way mergesort, it's important to remember that the work done per level increases as the number of levels increases. Specifically, in your merge step, you need to switch from a normal 2-way merge to a special 3-way merge. At each step in the merge, you need to determine which of the lists has the smallest unused element. In a two-way merge, you just compare the front elements of the two lists against one another. In a three-way merge, there are more comparisons required because you have to find the lowest element out of three elements.

Generalizing this to a k-way mergesort, the number of layers will be log<sub>k</sub> n, but the work for the merge will be higher than this. It's possible to do a k-way merge of n total elements in time O(n log k) by using binary heaps, so more work is required as k increases.

Interestingly, if we talk about the amount of work required overall, then we can see that we need to do O(n log k) work across log<sub>k</sub> n levels. This gives us a total runtime of O(n log k log<sub>k</sub> n). Using the change-of-base formula for logarithms, which says that log<sub>k</sub> n = log<sub>2</sub> n / log<sub>2</sub> k, we see that the runtime will be

> O(n log k log<sub>k</sub> n)
>
> = O(n log k (log n / log k))
>
> = O(n log n)

In other words, there isn't an asymptotic difference between the algorithms when you choose different values of k. The drop in levels due to a higher splitting factor is offset by an increased amount of work per level.

To figure out which algorithm is best, the best option would be to run them all and see what happens. Due to caching effects and locality of reference, I suspect that the answer might at some level depend on the particular architecture you're using.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Big-O complexity, it doesn't matter.

Regular merge sort is `n * log_2(n)` which is equivalent to `n * (log(n) / log(2))`.  The `log(2)` is constant, so merge sort is simply `n * log(n)`

Tri-merge sort is `n * log_3(n)` which, using the same logic for regular merge sort, is simply `n * log(n)`

Given that both reduce to `O(n * log(n))`, it's not really possible to say which is *better*.

---

An alternate way to demonstrate why you can't just assume tri-merge to be better:

Assume a 3-way merge is better than a 2-way merge.
In general, assume an (N+1)-way merge is better than an N-way merge.

If this were true, it would be best to use an N-way merge where N is the number of elements you're sorting.  However, the merge step requires choosing the least element from N sources which requires `O(N)` time.
This means that the N-way merge sort runs in `O(N^2)` time, effectively making it [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).